# Specify path to execute from in hostfile for MPI

Tags: mpi, openmpi, mpich

Note: I'm currently using MPICH, but I'm open to switching to Open-MPI if what I want is easier in that MPI implementation.

I have a MPI program that I want to run across several nodes. However, these nodes are unfortunately not uniform with what's installed where on them. Unfortunately I do not have control over this. As a result, I need to set the definition of "home" individually for a couple of machines. Is there a way to do this in the hostfile?

Something like:

```
localhost
host1 STARTPATH=/path/for/host1
host2 STARTPATH=/path/for/host2
```

etc.

Within these directories everything is identical.

Comment: Did you try using a config file, like `mpiexec -configfile myconfig`? In there you can specify exactly what you want per host (number of processes, executable, etc)

Comment: After further research going off your comment, it appears this WILL work in OpenMPI, but it WON'T work in MPICH, I think. Do you know if that's the case?

Comment: I used that with MPICH a while ago and it worked for me... I can't guarantee it will for you, but I've got a good feeling about it.